# yum update exits with "Didn't install any keys"

Tags: centos, yum, gpg

I just installed Centos 6.7 on Virtualbox and ran `yum update` with this output:

```
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Importing GPG key 0xC105B9DE:
 Userid : CentOS-6 Key (CentOS 6 Official Signing Key) <centos-6-key@centos.org>
 Package: centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201508042137.x86_64/6.7)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Is this ok [y/N]:

Didn't install any keys
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This update is for installing repository keys, hence asking for confirmation as installing wrong keys has security implications.

The error message is because the default is *not installing* as the capital N shows. As you have pressed ENTER, it displayed the error.

Please run `yum update` again and press Y when presented with this message.

Comment: Perfect!   Pressing 'Y' imported key successfully!  Couldn't find this anywhere else and all other solutions didn't work.  Thank you.